# Closing windows form

Tags: visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

im developing windows application using c#. i want to close the application and show new form after clicking the button, i did it, but every time i cliecked the button, it shows the another windows and when i going to task manager that form isntance still running. i want avoid that. i am using this.close() function to exit from the form.

Comment: why do you want to close the entire application? If all you are trying to accomplish is showing a new form, you can just hide or close your first form and then show the second form.

Comment: If you want to have some delay between hiding & showing forms (maybe you're seeing the transtition and you don't want that), you can always use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x)` to wait `x` miliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose you have `Form1` and `Form2`.

The code in `Form1` should be something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form2 = new Form2();
        _form2.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(_form2_VisibleChanged);
    }

    void _form2_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_form2.Visible)
            Show();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Hide();
        _form2.Show();
    }
}
```

And in `Form2` all you need to do is:

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
}
```

Of course, you must suscribe to the event `FormClosing` in `Form2`, but if you do it through the designer (Form `Properties`, clicking on `Events` icon) just paste those two lines inside the method it creates)

**What is this code doing?**

**In `Form1`:**

- Create a instance of `Form2`
- In `Form1_FormClosing` method, all we do is ***hide*** the form instead of closing it when the user closes it, and showing the instance of `Form2`
- Suscribe to the `VisibleChanged` event
- When the event fires, if the instance of `Form2` isn't visible, then `Form1` appears.

**In `Form2`**:

- The 2nd of the above steps, but without showing anything.

If you want to do it when you click on a button, all you need to do is do the same but on the `Click` event on the button instead of the `FormClosing` event.

Comment: exactly i need to shuffle between two forms. its works fine, but only problem is everytime i shuffle between two forms it is creating new instance of the form, wat i need to do is avoid to that happen. when  ever i shuffle between the forms, only shold have two forms, instead of havinf more instances. i hope u will get my scenario.